Formulation of the axiom of separation that doesn't require natural numbers?
The separation schema deals with a proposition ψ(w, u1, ..., uk). Now, this requires that we have already defined the natural numbers. Is there a formulation of it that does not require that? I'm writing an introductory article about set theory and I would have to split the enunciation of the axioms to define natural numbers before proceeding, which wouldn't be ideal.

Can you state the axiom of separation as Zermelo did in your post?  I think it would help you and others to answer your question.

Use x', x'', x''',...

Maybe, in your text, you have to avoid also the page numbers ...

See Wikipedia formulation of axiom schema of separation which only needs one variable. Are you talking about axiom schema of replacement?…

Generate the natuals from the null set. It's real easy. Or posit zeeo and use nested successor functions instead of integers.

Separation, a.k.a. specification, schema does not have such a proposition. The replacement schema does, but even Wikipedia gives a simplified version without labeled variables due to Levy, which is equivalent to the original replacement assuming extensionality, pairing, union and powerset.

@MauroALLEGRANZA that doesn't work.

@Conifold I'm referring to the axiom of separation as stated here.

@MauroALLEGRANZA I meant using x', x'', x'''... That still relies on the concept of natural number, because you would have to write something like x', ..., x^{(n)}.

Jocking apart, it is only a way to name variables: call them xa, xb, xc,... or directly a,b,c.. and there is no number involved. The issue is not relevant at all: we do not learn counting using set theory.

@MauroALLEGRANZA that's true, but still I have some issues with using ... in a list, since there is no way to remove that ... and write the list explicitly wthout using natural numbers (the number of the elements of the list is not fixed.)

The gist here is that you only need plural quantification or equivalently the way to identify entities in the domain, the set of natural numbers is a much stronger concept with additional arithmetic operations and the critical successor function along with induction axiom schema...

Why not just use specification instead? It has no numbered variables.

A similar issue is discussed into George Tourlakis, Lectures in Logic and Set Theory. Volume 1: Mathematical Logic (Cambridge UP, 2003), Ch.I.1. First Order Languages, page 9.

@MauroALLEGRANZA thank you. Would you recomment this book, in general?

@MauroALLEGRANZA I would like to study logic from an actual textbook. Could you recommend some books that are precise under the formal aspect, in your opinion?

This question on Math SE talks about what I think is roughly the same issue you’re concerned with here: In order to talk about formulas of “arbitrary length”, you need to have some concept of an infinitude of “arbitrary large” natural numbers available prior to the development of set theory. The answer by Noah Schweber argues persuasively that this is unavoidable.
One way to maybe (kind of) finesse your way around this is with a finitely axiomatizable set theory like NBG. Then your axioms and proofs only involve formulas you can actually write down, thus avoiding the need for a notion of “arbitrary long” formulas.

There is an important distinction between metalanguage natural numbers and object-language natural numbers.  Only the metalanguage natural numbers are needed for formulating the schema of separation, and for that matter for just about any interesting theory of logic.  Therefore you don't have to introduce the (object-language) natural numbers formally before developing set theory.
